# summarize word count for a timeframe

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have the below table which stores the response text and the keyword search associated with it.

create table nlp.search(response string, words string,inquiry_time timestamp);

insert into nlp.search values('how to reset password','reset word password',TIMESTAMP ("2021-09-19 05:30:00+00"));
insert into nlp.search values('how to reset password','reset passphrase',TIMESTAMP ("2021-09-20 07:30:00+00"));
insert into nlp.search values('how to reset password','password',TIMESTAMP ("2021-09-16 08:30:00+00"));
insert into nlp.search values('how to reset password','reset',TIMESTAMP ("2021-09-14 08:30:00+00"));

I want to provide a summary report in this format
response and the count of each individual words associated with it.

response                                     individual_word_count
how to reset password                        reset(3) word(1) password(2) passphrase(1)

also the timestamp column inquiry_time can be passed to narrow down the date range and the summary values must be computed accordingly

e.g for timeframe filter 2021-09-19 till 2021-09-20

response                                     individual_word_count
how to reset password                        reset(2) word(1) password(1) passphrase(1)

can this be accomplished using a view?

Comment: This is what i have tired so far. I need to get the  timefilter working.                   
select response ,ind_words, count(ind_words) from (
select response,split(split_word,' ') as individual_word from (
select  response,array_concat_agg(split(words)) as split_words from nlp.word_collcation
group by response  ) a , unnest(a.split_words) split_word ) b,unnest(b.individual_word) ind_words
group by 1,ind_words

Comment: Please read "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)". Also, provide the minimal code necessary to demonstrate what you tried IN THE QUESTION, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select response, word, count(1) ndividual_word_count
from `nlp.search`, 
unnest(split(words, ' ')) word
where date(inquiry_time) between '2021-09-19' and '2021-09-20'
group by response, word
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

> I Need to display the word and count in 1 single column

use below then

```
select response, 
  string_agg(format('%s (%i)', word, individual_word_count)) counts
from (
  select response, word, count(1) individual_word_count
  from `nlp.search`, 
  unnest(split(words, ' ')) word
  where date(inquiry_time) between '2021-09-19' and '2021-09-20'
  group by response, word
)
group by response
```

with output

[image]

Comment: I Need to display the word and count in 1 single column like this. how to pivot this value.                response   word_count                                                                                                                                    how to reset password   reset(2),word(1),password(1),passphrase(1)

Comment: The date parameter here date(inquiry_time) between '2021-09-19' and '2021-09-20'   will vary. can we set this as a parameter? users might pass different date combinations and I don't want this to be hardcoded. I am wondering if this is possible.